# Posting articles and/or code

Tags: support, source-code, featured-tag

Is there any place or site in the world of Stack Exchange where people can post articles and/or code to share with the rest of the world, etc.? Possible articles and code which can be voted up and down, edited, corrected, etc.? A bit like codeproject or codeplex?

Comment: Try [Github](http://github.org). Let's focus Stack Exchange on its  Q&A specialization, and we'll promise that we won't ask Github if we can post programming questions on their site. Specialization is key to success.  One thing some SO users like to do is post a link to their Github repo in their SO profile, and vice-versa, so the two sites can be complimentary.

Answer (score 6):

In a word, **no**.

About the closest you'll get to what you're looking for is [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). However, and to echo other answers, it's still:

> A ***question** and **answer** site for sharing code from projects you are working on for peer review*

Rather than a place to publicise it and/or share it with the world.

What's wrong with [github](https://github.com/) (codeplex, codeproject too) or similar? - Post your project/code, people find it and if it's good enough they'll:

> ## use it, star it, fork it, share it...

Comment: Use it, star it, fork it, share it, [technologic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UoPplpBPQxQ)...

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi I feel an expensive ad-campaign for Github coming on!

Comment: That would be a _perfect_ campaign

Answer (score 3):

No. If you look on the [main website](https://stackexchange.com/), there is in enormous, impossible to miss lettering:

> expert **answers** to your **questions**

It may just be me, but I don't see how sharing code or articles with people counts as question-asking. I'm pretty sure the following in [the about section](https://stackexchange.com/about) *directly* covers this:

> We welcome questions that are clear and specific, representing real problems that you face; Stack Exchange is not the place for conversation, opinions, or socializing.

And it's pretty explicitly just that.

Comment: Well... since we are allowed to answer our own questions (I know something and I am going to share...! Even when nobody asked) and since we have discussion forums (lets share opinions whiles nobody asked)... I feels logical to have an outlet for the people who DO have something to tell te rest of the world without beging asked.

Comment: @Martin Yes, that is true, we do allow askers to answer their own questions. However, the requirement for this is that the question _must_ be able to stand on its own - in other words, posting `How can I make websites?` and then answering with a long guide - however detailed - is not acceptable. The question, by itself, doesn't fit the Q&A format.

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can come is asking and answering your own question.  Asking a question then posting an article as an answer will not be accepted.  But if you have encountered and solved a specific problem, it is very good practice and encouraged to post your problem as a question, then answer with your research immediately.